# Widget stays always active even after toggle

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a widget that is just a basic toggle that returns a true (2) or false (1) value based on the position of the toggle. I am really not sure why, but the widget never turns off even when I try and toggle it (i.e always stays active).

Checking console log, I can see the value it is trying to send is a 1, but the widget does not seem to update its position or value to the attribute.

This is using javascript and angular.

```
let settings;
let attributeService;
let utils;
let translate;
let $scope;
let map;

self.onInit = function() {
    self.ctx.ngZone.run(function() {
        init();
        self.ctx.detectChanges(true);
    });
};


function init() {
    $scope = self.ctx.$scope;
    attributeService = $scope.$injector.get(self.ctx.servicesMap.get('attributeService'));
    utils = $scope.$injector.get(self.ctx.servicesMap.get('utils'));
    translate = $scope.$injector.get(self.ctx.servicesMap.get('translate'));
    $scope.toastTargetId = 'input-widget' + utils.guid();
    settings = utils.deepClone(self.ctx.settings) || {};
    settings.showResultMessage = utils.defaultValue(settings.showResultMessage, true);

    $scope.isValidParameter = true;
    $scope.dataKeyDetected = false;
    $scope.message = translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.no-entity-selected');

    settings.trueValue = utils.defaultValue(utils.customTranslation(settings.trueValue, settings.trueValue), true);
    settings.falseValue = utils.defaultValue(utils.customTranslation(settings.falseValue, settings.falseValue), false);

    map = {
        true: settings.trueValue,
        false: settings.falseValue
    };
    
    $scope.slideToggleValue = false;
    $scope.currentValue = map[$scope.slideToggleValue];

    $scope.attributeUpdateFormGroup = $scope.fb.group({slideToggleValue: [$scope.slideToggleValue]});

    $scope.changed = function() {
        $scope.slideToggleValue = $scope.attributeUpdateFormGroup.get('slideToggleValue').value;
        $scope.currentValue = map[$scope.slideToggleValue];
        $scope.updateAttribute();
    };

    if (self.ctx.datasources && self.ctx.datasources.length) {
        var datasource = self.ctx.datasources[0];
        if (datasource.type === 'entity') {
            if (datasource.entityType === 'DEVICE') {
                if (datasource.entityType && datasource.entityId) {
                    $scope.entityName = datasource.entityName;
                    if (settings.widgetTitle && settings.widgetTitle.length) {
                        $scope.titleTemplate = utils.customTranslation(settings.widgetTitle, settings.widgetTitle);
                    } else {
                        $scope.titleTemplate = self.ctx.widgetConfig.title;
                    }
    
                    $scope.entityDetected = true;
                }
            } else {
                $scope.message = translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.not-allowed-entity');
            }
        }
        if (datasource.dataKeys.length) {
            if (datasource.dataKeys[0].type !== "attribute") {
                $scope.isValidParameter = false;
            } else {
                $scope.currentKey = datasource.dataKeys[0].name;
                $scope.dataKeyType = datasource.dataKeys[0].type;
                $scope.dataKeyDetected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    self.ctx.widgetTitle = utils.createLabelFromDatasource(self.ctx.datasources[0], $scope.titleTemplate);

    $scope.updateAttribute = function() {
        if ($scope.entityDetected) {
            var datasource = self.ctx.datasources[0];
            var valueToSend = $scope.slideToggleValue === 2 ? 2 : 1;
            console.log("ValueToSend: ", valueToSend)
            attributeService.saveEntityAttributes(
                datasource.entity.id,
                'SHARED_SCOPE',
                [
                    {
                        key: $scope.currentKey,
                        value: valueToSend
                        // value: $scope.slideToggleValue || false
                    }
                ]
            ).subscribe(
                function success() {
                    if (settings.showResultMessage) {
                        $scope.showSuccessToast(translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.update-successful'), 1000, 'bottom', 'left', $scope.toastTargetId);
                    }
                },
                function fail() {
                    if (settings.showResultMessage) {
                        $scope.showErrorToast(translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.update-failed'), 'bottom', 'left', $scope.toastTargetId);
                    }
                }
            );
        console.log("1: ", parseInt($scope.slideToggleValue))
        }
    };
}

self.onDataUpdated = function() {
    try {
        if ($scope.dataKeyDetected) {
            // $scope.slideToggleValue = self.ctx.data[0].data[0][1] === 'true';
            console.log("A:",self.ctx.data[0].data[0][1])
            $scope.slideToggleValue = self.ctx.data[0].data[0][1] === 2 ? 2 : 1
            $scope.currentValue = map[$scope.slideToggleValue];
            $scope.attributeUpdateFormGroup.get('slideToggleValue').patchValue($scope.slideToggleValue);
            self.ctx.detectChanges();
            console.log("B:",self.ctx.data[0].data)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

self.onResize = function() {}

self.typeParameters = function() {
    return {
        maxDatasources: 1,
        maxDataKeys: 1,
        singleEntity: true
    }
}

self.onDestroy = function() {}
```

my toggle switch:

```
                    <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="slideToggleValue" (change)="changed()"
                                      aria-label="{{'widgets.input-widgets.switch-timeseries-value' | translate}}"
                                      class="custom-slide-toggle">
                        {{ slideToggleValue.checked ? 2 : 1 }}  
                    </mat-slide-toggle>
```